Show that a sphere bundle over S^2 is trivial
I want to show that the following sphere bundle is trivial. Consider $S^2=\{(z,x)\in \mathbb C\times \mathbb R \mid |z|^2+x^2=1\}$ with the open cover ${U_1,U_2}$ of $S^2$, where $U_1=S^2\setminus (0,1)$ and $U_2=S^2\setminus (0,-1)$. Let $\pi:E\rightarrow S^2$ be the sphere bundle with cocycles $g_{12},g_{21}$ defined by
\begin{align}
\bigr(g_{12}(z,x)\bigr)(w,y)&=(\frac {z^2}{|z|^2}w,y);\\
\bigr(g_{21}(z,x)\bigr)(w,y)&=(\frac {\overline z^2}{|z|^2}w,y),
\end{align}
for any $(w,y)\in S^2\subset \mathbb C\times \mathbb R$. That is, $g_{12}(z,x)$ is the rotation around the 'real axis' of angle $\theta=2\arg z$. In some lecture notes I am following, it claim that it is easily shown that this is the trivial bundle $S^2\times S^2$, but I cannot prove this.
I know that I need to find two functions $\lambda_i:U_i\to O(3), \quad i=1,2$ such that
\begin{align}
Id=\lambda_1\circ g_{12} \circ \lambda_2^{-1}\quad \text{on }U_{12}=U_1\cap U_2.
\end{align}
It occurred to me that maybe the following choice of $\lambda_i'$s would work:
\begin{align}
\bigr(\lambda_1(z,x)\bigr)(w,y)&=(\frac {\overline z}{|z|}w,y);\\
\bigr(\lambda_2(z,x)\bigr)(w,y)&=(\frac { z}{|z|}w,y).
\end{align}
However, on $U_1$ (or $U_2$, respectively) I run into the problem that $z/|z|$ is not defined at $z=0$ and I am not able to go around this problem. Any suggestion is appreciated.

A couple of thoughts: (i) Do you have geometric intuition about how the two trivialized bundles $U_{k} \times S^2$ are glued over $U_1 \cap U_2$? (ii) Do you know the fundamental group of $SO(3)$, particularly the fact that a curve effecting rotation of $4\pi$ about an axis is homotopic to the identity (while a rotation by $2\pi$ is not)?
